# Access nested structure

Tags: r

Are there some nice designs to call data in a nested structure e.g.

```
a<-list(list(LETTERS[1:3],LETTERS[1:3]),list(LETTERS[4:6]))
lapply(a,function(x) lapply(x, function(x) x))
```

but unlist is not a option.

Comment: Your sample code doesn't work. Can you post a working sample and what you want to do? Also please explain why `unlist` is not an option?

Comment: sry I edit the example.

Comment: but I still don't see what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as good as @SimonO101's answer but just for providing as an alternative you can do it using `do.call`

```
> do.call(c,do.call(c, a))
[1] "A" "B" "C" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"
```

Also using `Reduce`

```
> do.call(c, Reduce(c, a))
[1] "A" "B" "C" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursive `lapply`... a.k.a `rapply`?

```
rapply( a , c )
[1] "A" "B" "C" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"
```